# Selenium Upload File when style="display:none;"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, display

I am getting an error " Element  is not reachable by keyboard"  Can you guys please help me in it. I just want to attach the PDF file but as the cusror goes on it i am unable to find click on it nor upload file on it.

Code is:-

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"registerproduct\"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/label"));
uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Downloads\\kemgo-auction-detail-574.pdf");
```

The Html is:-

```
<div class="col s12">
 <div class="file-field input-field">
    <div class="">
         <input id="btn_myFileInput" onchange="checkimagetype()" name="productsheet" style="display:none;" type="file">
         <span class="attached sp_head">
          <label for="btn_myFileInput" class="gray-lite attach_circle left"> 
              <i class="fa fa-paperclip small"></i>
           </label>
         <span class="sp_head">
        Attach specification sheet                                            </span>
          <span id="fileinput-msg"></span> </span>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Can you guys help me in uploading file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your *code trials* the *WebElement* to pass the file path is not the `<label>` tag. You should target the `<input>` tag. Additionally the `<input>` tag is having *style* attribute set to **display: none;**. You can use the following code block to upload the file :

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btn_myFileInput']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", uploadElement);
uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Downloads\\kemgo-auction-detail-574.pdf");
```

Comment: One thing.. I usually get the error:-  "Element <i class="fa fa-paperclip small"> is not reachable by keyboard" 
what can be the main problem? It is not only here but at many other points.

Comment: Element <input id="btn_myFileInput" name="productsheet" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: The `<i>` tag attributes decorates the _appearance_ of `<label>` tag e.g.  _text_

Comment: `not reachable by keyboard` error arises out of **version** mismatch of the binaries you are using _JDK_,  _Selenium Client_ , _ChromeDriver_  and _Chrome_

Comment: How can i upload image HTML is:-

<div class="row_dv text-center">
                    <label class="drag_upload">                        
                        <input id="rempic" name="imageh" value="" type="hidden">
                        <input name="imaged" style="display:none" id="image123" onchange="checkimage()" type="file">
                        <p class="gray-lite"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload large"></i></p>
                        <p class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-upload">Picture Upload</p>
                   </label>
                </div>

Comment: @RAHUL Can you please raise a new question with your new requirement. We will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution and I think it can solve other cases. And I will explain clearly about my code

> ```
>     driver.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
>
>     WebElement uploadImage = driver.findElementByXPath("*<your_xPath_element>*");
>
>     String scriptOn = "arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display: block')";
>
>     driver.executeScript(scriptOn, uploadImage);
>
>     uploadImage.sendKeys("*<your_image_URL>*");
>
>     String scriptOff = "arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display: none')";
>
>     driver.executeScript(scriptOff, uploadImage);
> ```

Explanation:

Pre-condition:

driver: FFDriver

language: Java

Steps:

Line 1: Because it's a hidden element so u don't know when it appears => that why you need to wait for page that full load

Line 2: Define the element that u want to detect, don't worry that it can't detect
example my xPath: *//input[@accept='image/*']*

Line 3: Define new value for Style attribute that as u expected
example URL = "path/01.png"

Line 4: execute command Element's current style = new value ('style','display: block')
=> it makes the hidden element to show

Line 5: Now your expectation element is show, so u can sendkeys (image URL) to it

Line 6 + 7: return raw state to this element

Answer (score 0):

Make the input field visible using element Id, when `style="display:none;"`

```
 public void makeInputElementVisible(){
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('your_element_id').style.display='block';");
    }
```

Make the input field visible using css selector, when `style="display:none;"`

```
 public void makeInputElementVisible(){
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor.executeScript("document.querySelector('your_css_selector_for_input_field').style.display='block';");
    }
```